# iPod Touch WiFi strength declining

Tags: ipod-touch, wifi

Over the last few weeks I have noticed that some WiFi access points just aren't registering on my iPod Touch. It used to connect to my home WiFi as soon as I pulled up in the car outside, and got that 'meep' noise as emailed synced.

Now whenever I turn it on, it doesn't always connect to the Access Point. Even when it is connected the signal strength is only 1 bar, whereas before it was always full(ish) strength. The Access Point is 8 feet away outside my bedroom, on the landing.

I don't know if it's related but about 4 months ago the iPod Touch went down the toilet. So I washed it with plenty of clean water, and left in a tub of silica gel type stuff for a few days before charging and it's worked pretty much fine ever since. Apart from one brief episode a couple of months ago when the screen was flashing between the icons and a full white display for a few seconds.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions / recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I lost the damn thing now.

I was going to look into a 'refurbishment programme' that I believe Apple did, but isn't widely publicised.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like corrosion in either the antenna or antenna connection.  If you are a DIY-type, you could open it up, check it, and perhaps fix it if it is the antenna connection.  Otherwise, time for a new Touch.

Comment: any idea how to open it up ?